# Is it possible to output a calculation using multiple values from multiple columns in different tables within a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 9 different tables and I'm trying to SUM using a single query and multiple table joins.

A "Job" table contains foreign keys from the different "Material" tables:
Material_1_ID, Material_2_ID, Material_3_ID, etc. and also includes the amount of material of each type used for the job.

The Material tables (Material_1, Material_2, Material_3, etc) themselves each have columns:
Material_ID, Material_Name, Cost per gram

I'm trying to multiply for each material_ID the `cost per gram` * `material_used`

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('$ ', ROUND(job_test4.Mat_1_Used * `Cost per gram`,2)) AS `Total Job Cost` 
  FROM Material_1
  JOIN job_test4 
    ON Material_1.Material_1_ID = job_test4.Material_1_ID
```

This returns the correct values for material_1.

However, if I try to include Material2 and/or Material3 etc, the result is being returned with the `cost per gram` of Material 1 only so the final summation is wrong.  Is it possible to return the correct result within 1 query?  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT job_id
     , job_name
     , completed
     , CONCAT('$ ', ROUND(job_test4.Mat_1_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2) 
                  + ROUND(job_test4.Mat_2_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2)

                  + ROUND(job_test4.Mat_3_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2) 
                  + ROUND(job_test4.Mat_4_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2)
                  + ROUND(job_test4.Mat_5_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2) 
                  + ROUND(job_test4.Mat_6_Used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2)
                  + ROUND(job_test4.sup_mat_used * `Cost per cu.in./gram`,2))

`Cost per Job` 
  FROM Material_1
  JOIN job_test4 
    ON Material_1.Material_1_ID = job_test4.Material_1_ID;
```

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema design.

Comment: If Material tables are all identical in structure, really should be one table with another field for MaterialType.

Comment: Thank you I will consider this.  The issue I run into is that one of the printers (1 out of 4 actually) has the possibility of having 7 different types of materials, while the other 3 only have 1 type (Material_ID_1).  What I could do is lay all this information out in a single table, but was hoping to have them related.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: And Job table should have a related dependent JobDetails table with 1 MaterialID field and 1 MaterialUsed field. Otherwise, yes, should be able to include Material tables joined to respective fields in Job table and do calcs.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  Having 1 material table, and 1 jobdetails table with all the materials used even for a single job will do the trick.  Thanks!